# How do you translate (char)B00000001 (c++) to the python equivalent?

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to translate a C++ library to python script, that essentially controls a quadrature decoder (LS7366R). The python script will run on a raspberry pi using the spidev library to handle the transfer of data.

The first thing I tried to do is to dissect and analyse each line of the c++ [library](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxiaW5namVmZmRvdWJsZXBlbmR1bHVtfGd4OjMyY2RjMDZhOTlmOGRiYTc). Unfortunately my knowledge of C++ is not too advanced and I can't understand what this means.

```
this->spiTransfer((char)B00000011);
```

I don't understand what (char)B00000011 does, let alone translate it to python.

Could anyone help me translate and understand what this means? Is it a series of bytes? How would I go about sending the data using the function xfer2 in the spidev python library?

In case it is needed, [here's](https://sites.google.com/site/bingjeffdoublependulum/rotary-encoders) the author of the library explaining how the decoder works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `B` (or `b`) prefix before a numeric constant indicates it is in binary (this is a common extension, but is non-standard).  `00000011` is 3 in binary, so the line `this->spiTransfer((char)B00000011);` is literally just `this->spiTransfer((char)3);`.  `(char)3` equates to the ASCII "End of Text" character.

Comment: I am curious, what compilers support that extension? Any linkable docs?

Comment: GCC has support for [binary constants](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html), though it is usually done using the prefix `0b`.

Comment: I know about that `gcc` extension, I looked into this recently for another question and I did not see any That use `B` in the beginning. It also would be ambiguous with identifiers too.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense.
So essentially to transfer the data over I would essentially just use spi.xfer2([3]) and that's it?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Also, since the original code for this was written for the Arduino, it is using its [compiler extensions](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/IntegerConstants#.Uw9tPfldV8E).

Comment: +1 neat, TIL Arduino allows a leading `B` for integer constants. Although, I wonder why not just use `0b` and skip the ambiguity in the grammar?